# Couchbase Lite DocumentUpdater does not update the db

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

Here is my code to update the document:

```
        doc.update(new Document.DocumentUpdater() {
        @Override
        public boolean update(UnsavedRevision newRevision) {
            Map < String, Object > properties = newRevision.getUserProperties()
           properties.put("timeCreated", "348390284");
           properties.put("name", "231321");
           return true;
        }
    });
```

When I run a query and iterate over the result rows using the following code:

```
    Database db = getDB(ID);
    Query query  = db.createAllDocumentsQuery();
    query.setDescending(true);

    try {
        QueryEnumerator result = query.run();
        for (Iterator<QueryRow> it = result; it.hasNext(); ) {
            QueryRow row = it.next();
            row.getDocument().getProperties();
        }
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {}
```

row doesn't have any of the updates I put in the updater. I am getting something like this:

```
row -> size 2
"conflict" -> "size=0"
"rev" -> "1-ac2065458743..."
```

I am stuck at this point and unsure how to fix it.

Comment: Which version of Couchbase are you using?  You're getting two docs back from your query.  Do they have the original contents you created them with?

Comment: This is the line in my Gradle file `compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:+'` Originally, the document is empty (I created new documents) I was trying to get the items I put into the properties but when I do an all doc query, each row does not have my content

Comment: Just a bit of context about where I call this updater. In my android web server, I want to save the payload as the payload comes to the server. I create a new thread to handle each request, and in that thread, I use the updater.

Answer (score 0):

`UnsavedRevision.getUserProperties()` returns the new `Map` instance. So you need to set it back by calling `setUserProperties()` method to the revision before returning true.

Following codes is from Couchbase Lite Sample code. [LINK](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html)

```
Document doc = database.getDocument(myDocId);
doc.update(new Document.DocumentUpdater() {
    @Override
    public boolean update(UnsavedRevision newRevision) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = newRevision.getUserProperties();
        properties.put("title", title);
        properties.put("notes", notes);
        newRevision.setUserProperties(properties); <<----
        return true;
    }
});
```

I hope this helps you.

Thanks!